# Разыскивается - проверочное слово - рОзыск!

Tags: орфография

**Разыскивается** - проверочное слово - **рОзыск**!
Вот и вся логика русского языка?
Почему так?

Comment: А почему не проверить ещё и гласную в окончании?

Comment: @I_CaR, вы тут свои порядки не устанавливайте. Да, shampar бывает излишне образен и не всегда корректен, но вам-то лично он ничего плохого не сказал. Не переходите на личности.

Answer (score 5):

Фонематический принцип письма: розыскать-розыск, фонетический принцип письма: разыскать - розыск. **Вот и вся логика — разные  принципы**.

**Пояснение**.

Правило написания приставок на З/С в современной формулировке было принято в ходе реформы 1918 года, при этом окончательно **был закреплен фонетический,  не фонематический (основной) принцип письма.**

Написание приставок на З/С всегда отличалось большой нестабильностью. Это связано с тем, что эти приставки изначально не имели редуцированного гласного «ъ» на конце, как другие приставки, поэтому фонетическое чередование З/С отражалось в устной речи, а потом закрепилось и на письме .

Но уже с XIII века наряду с таким традиционным (ФОНЕТИЧЕСКИМ) письмом появляется ФОНЕМАТИЧЕСКАЯ ЗАПИСЬ приставок через *з*.  Противостояние этих двух принципов (с колебаниями то в сторону одного, то в сторону другого) продолжалось до проведения реформы 1918 года.

**Примеры дореформенных правил:** [Русская дореформенная орфография](http://www.gpedia.com/ru/gpedia)
1) 1847 год: **«роздѣ́лъ, устар., то же, что раздѣ́лъ»;** «роздѣ́льный, устар., то же, что раздѣ́льный»; «розмѣ́нный, устар. то же, что размѣ́нный»[14]. **Позже (во второй половине XIX века) в трудах Грота и во всех учебниках указывается, что приставка роз- пишется через «о» только, если на неё падает ударение.** Этот принцип (пример, когда этимологический принцип написания уступил фонетическому) принят и в современной русской орфографии.

2) Приставки, оканчивающиеся на -з (из-, воз-, раз-, роз-, низ-), **перед последующей с** **сохраняли з:** разсказъ, разсуждать, возсоединить. **Приставки без-, через-, чрез- всегда имели на конце -з:** безполезный, безкровный, безтактный, безсонница; черезчуръ, чрезполосица.

[О слове "розыск" (современное изменение правила "розыск - разыскной)](http://www.gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_2_razysknoj/)